# Check for alternating 0s and 1s using recursion in haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I want to write a recursive function to check whether a String (of 0s and 1s) is alternating.

For example:

```
In:  101010
Out: True

In:  110010
Out: False
```

How can I write such a function, and how am I to understand its logic?

Comment: Recursion is not the best way to solve this.

Comment: Is the input a list, or an integer (interpreted as a binary number)?

Comment: @dave:lst or string, what u think esier in this context

Comment: This smells like an interview question. Using recursion for a simple task in an odd fashion. :-)

Comment: @BenSwayne I don't think it's an interview question. Saugata is definitely new to haskell.

Comment: @AndrewC `answer xs = and $ zipWith (/=) xs (drop 1 xs)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're asking for a function to check whether the list alternates between 0 and 1.

I think this is a nice way of solving this problem with recursion:

```
alternates ('1':'1':_) = False   -- always false if it repeats
alternates ('0':'0':_) = False   -- always false if it repeats
alternates [] = True
alternates (x:xs) = alternates xs
```

The last line works this way:
We know that if `xs` has an element in it, it's not the same as `x` because the first two cases checked for that, so we can just move on and check starting from the front of `xs`.

We need `""`, and `"1"` or `"0"` to give True for consistency; alternating means no repeats.

Comment: at last i got my mentor. and it works.Thanx, mentor